# How to get the all quote ids in cart items from magento soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, soap, quote

I have created a soap client Api for magento, my requirement is to get all quote id in shopping cart added items. How can i get this?

i am using `mservice.shoppingCartInfo(sessionid,quoteid,storeid)` here i am passing **storeid** as **null** and sessionid autenticated the problem is **i need to fetch all quoteid** which i am unable to fetch from added cart items.

Comment: i am using asp.net soap api v1

Comment: i am using mservice.shoppingCartInfo(sessionid,quoteid,storeid) here i am passing storeid as null and sessionid autenticated the problem is i need to fetch all quoteid which i am unable to fetch from added cart items